# Outlook interop opening too many items causes error

Tags: c#, interop, outlook

My goal is to open shared calendars for analysis and database tracing.

The point is I manage to open the items but after a few hundreds, I get an exception.
It explains that the administrator (security reasons) limited the amount of simultenaous openned items.

I can understand this so I've tried to close each item after reading it. But I still get the error. The problem appears when I'm reading user properties.

Here is a sample of my program:

```
Recipient recipient = mapiNamespace.CreateRecipient("John Doe");
if (recipient.Resolve())
{
    CalendarFolder = mapiNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(recipient, OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
    outlookCalendarItems = CalendarFolder.Items;
    outlookCalendarItems.IncludeRecurrences = false;
}
else
{
    Console.Write("Failed to open Calendar");
    return;
}

foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AppointmentItem item in outlookCalendarItems)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Subject + " -> " + item.Start.ToLongDateString());   //=> Ok, no problem
    UserProperty up = item.UserProperties.Find("Test");                   //=> Problem if too many items
    if( up!= null )
    {
        Console.Write("UserProperty Value: " + up.Value);
    }

    ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._AppointmentItem)item).Close(OlInspectorClose.olDiscard);   //=> Problem if too many items
    Console.WriteLine();

}

Console.ReadKey();
```

Any idea on how to properly close the items?

Comment: You need to call Marshal.ReleaseComObject on EVERY Outlook instance you touch. Call it until it in a loop until it returns zero.

Comment: Right, I had to force the release of each item.                      System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(item); Thanks!

Comment: Awesome.. glad that I was able to help.. just keep in mind that COM object or when dealing with Interop, it's different when Marshalling , Invoking and Releasing objects.. I use to do tons of COM with Delphi and learned that early on about 15 yrs ago.. vote up when you get a chanc

Comment: Signature is removed, Please refer the FAQ.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to using `Masrhal.ReleaseCOMObject`, you should also avoid using multiple dot notation (e.g. `item.UserProperties.Find`) - the compiler will create an implicit variable for each "." - you cannot explicitly release such variables.

Secondly, do not use "foreach" loops - it keeps all the collection elements referenced until the loop terminates. Use a "for" loop.

Thirdly, looping through all items in a folder is always a terrible idea - use `MAPIFolder.GetTable`. Or use the `MAPITable` object in Redemption (I am its author): http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/mapitable.htm

Answer (score 0):

This is how i did it (just in case anyone comes accross this thread):

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(_calendar_item);
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

Comment: Well, I came across it, and this is a good idea to try, since the `ReleaseComObject` did not get rid of the "Too many items open" error message.  Thanks!